# What side effects should one expect when method decorator replaces self?

Tags: python, decorator, self

I want to execute a method with a copy of the original `self` passed while execution.

Here is the code I'm talking about:

```
def protect_self(func):
    from copy import copy
    from functools import wraps
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self_copy = copy(self)
        return func(self_copy, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

In my understanding the copy function creates a new object of the same type and
copies the `__dict__` of the old one to the new object (using references, so
changes to actual object instances in `__dict__` will still affect the original object).

Does this mean I can be sure that the decorated method cannot modify `__dict__` of
the original instance?

Just to make sure: I don't need a secure sandbox behaviour. My purpose is just
to have a single object instanciated which I will use as a factory. The
*protected* method should be possible to modify the passed `self` but it should
be reseted afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP clarified in a comment that the purpose is to be threadsafe, then there's an obvious issue -- `copy.copy` itself **isn't** threadsafe, in addition to the issue already pointed out, that `copy.copy` makes a **shallow** copy and so (while `self.__dict__` itself won't be modified) mutable objects can perfectly well get altered.  Using `copy.deepcopy` deals with this (at a potentially hefty price in terms of performance) but in a sense even worsens the issue of thread-safety (since deep-copying can take so much longer than shallow-copying, the risk of a race condition actually occurring grows by leaps and bounds -- not that I'm in any way, shape or form *recommending* having race conditions that occur "only rarely", mind!-).

If you have to make originally-unsafe methods thread-safe, you'll have to bite the bullet and use locks (or a Queue and an auxiliary thread to serialize the operations) -- I guess that if you further need to silently ignore the methods' attempts to alter objects, you'll moreover have to `deepcopy` everything (why stop at `self` -- what if those methods were altering **globals**, for example?!-).  Seem a very iffy proposition to me.

Answer (score 2):

The copy makes it so the 'self' passed to the decorated function is a shallow copy of the original. The decorated function can't modify the original 'self' directly, although it can of course modify it through other means (if it has indirect access to it.) If any of the attributes of the object are mutable, it can effectively change the original 'self' by modifying the attributes.

Additionally, any piece of (arbitrary) Python code has indirect access to pretty much any object in the program. The decorated function could gain access to the original 'self' through stack inspection, or through the `gc` module, for example. Your usecase seems a little convoluted; are you sure you should be using a class instance for this?

Comment: Yeah maybe you're right. I'm aware that someone tries to get access to something in python he will succeed - thats also not what I want. Maybe this is just a poor attempt to make a method as much side-effect free as possible. I want the method to be threadsafe (regarding to `self`) _and_ that the return value is not determined by previous runs of the method.

Comment: Simply copying self doesn't do much to improve threadsafety, because mutable attributes will still be the same object referenced from both instances.